# Lowest Positive Difference between two tuples

Tags: algorithm

If I have an array which is sorted by the first element:
[(2021/01/01, 100), (2021/01/02, 5320), ..., (2021/01/07, 23)], how do I output an array such that each element holds the number of days between days from an input tuple t until a future date in the input array having the lowest positive difference between the number in tuple t and the number in the future date tuple.

For example,
[(2021/01/01, 100), (2021/01/02, 5320), (2021/01/04, 5319), (2021/01/09, 23)] has the solution:

[8, 2, 5, 0]

**Explanation:** For the first, 100 and 23 is closest and 9 - 1 = 8.

**My attempt:**

```
for i from 0 to n-1:
    m = inf
    for j from 1 to n:
        if a[i].value >= a[j].value and a[i].value - a[j].value < m:
               m = a[i].value - a[j].value
               update the current min date difference
    add to list of min date differences

return that list
```

I have written a `n^2` algorithm, but I'm trying to make it more efficient. My guess is that I can turn this into a binary tree but I'm having no luck. If anyone could guide my I'd appreciate it!

Comment: I added it @chux-ReinstateMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could visit the input in reverse order and build a balanced search tree (e.g. AVL, red-black, B-tree,...) from the already visited values, ordered by the number part of the tuples.

Values in a balanced search tree can be found in *O(logn)* time, and given (the path to) a node, the successor and predecessor nodes can be found in *O(1)* average time.

So find the predecessor and successor node in that tree based on the current value being visited. Either of these two will represent the minimum difference with the current number, and so output the corresponding day-difference in the result list at the current index.

Here is some pseudo code where I assume there is already an implementation of a balanced search tree. That balanced search tree should be capable of taking a comparator function so it knows how to compare two nodes, an `add` method, and `next` and `previous` methods on its nodes (interfaces may differ):

```py
function compare(x, y):  # two elements from the input array
    if x.value === y.value:  # equal? then prefer the earliest date:
        return x.date - y.date  # assuming this returns a signed number of days
    else:  
        return x.value - y.value

function getResult(a):
    tree = AVL(compare)  # keeps order by using the given compare function
    result = array(len(a))  # array of same length as a
    for i from n-1 downto 0:
        days = infinity
        node = tree.add(a[i])  # create an AVL node, insert it in the tree and return it
        successor = node.next()  # can return NIL when there is no successor
        if successor != NIL:
            days = abs(successor.date - node.date)
        predecessor = node.previous()
        if predecessor != NIL:
            days = min(days, abs(predecessor.date - node.date)
        result[i] = days

    result[n-1] = 0  # Optional, when you prefer 0 there instead of infinity
    return result
```